# XAudio2 in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator, xaudio2

I'm currently working on an audio project with XAudio2 and I've been using MSVC++ Express 2010. I wrote some basic functionalities, and I thought I'd try making a UI with Qt, so I followed the steps to be able to use Qt in my version of MSVC:

- Download the Qt source code
- Compile everything in MSVC with the cmd prompt
- Create a Makefile project that uses qmake & nmake
- Add the directories for the libs, includes, dlls in my project

And everything works fine.

Now, I would love to go the other way around and import my project into Qt Creator to use the Qt designer easily, and also because I would simply like to play with it and see if I like it.

So, I imported a simple console application I made using XAudio2, and I added the XAudio include path in the .pro:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Include"
```

The problem I get at compilation is:

```
main.obj:-1: error : LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CoInitializeEx@8 referenced in function _main
File not found: main.obj
```

The file is right there though, the compilation creates it:

```
C:\Qt\qtcreator-2.2.1\projects\test-build-desktop\debug
```

and I have no idea why Creator can't find it... Any ideas? Is it a libraby I need to include that would be automatically included when I worked in MSVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found my answer, but it was a hard one. So, 8 hours later, here it is. CoInitializeEx initializes a COM library for use by the calling thread, and some other stuff...

[CoInitializeEx Function Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms695279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The following link explains how to use COM objects with Qt.

[Using COM objects in Qt](http://www.trinitydesktop.org/docs/qt4/activeqt-container.html)

Basically, you add

```
CONFIG += qaxcontainer
```

to your `.pro` file

Also, for some reason, even though it has nothing to do with this, I had to use jom because nmake wouldn't work.